# Finetune Llama 2-7B using PDF document in Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model, fine-tuning, llama

Can someone give me ideas on how to fine-tune the Llama 2-7B model in Sagemaker using multiple PDF documents, please?

For now, I used pypdf and extracted the text from PDF but I don't know how to proceed after this. Even in the AWS documentation, they have only provided resources on fine-tuning using CSV.

Comment: Here's an example of fine-tuning with Llama2 on SageMaker: https://www.philschmid.de/sagemaker-llama2-qlora. You will have to adjust your training data and tokenize as expected for your Llama model.